# length of data to decrypt is invalid with rijndael cryptography

Tags: c#

the other links are not being useful to me.
i am encrypting string before saving in mysql database.that is working fine.but when i want to retrieve, its giving me length of data to encrypt is invalid error.
before my encryption requirement, i was using datatype of varchar size 500.now im using varbinary of size 800.can any1 advise me on the size too?

encryption method:

```
public static byte[] encryptStringToBytes(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        //create an Rijndael object
        using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
        {
            //create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            //create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return encrypted;
    }
```

decryption method:

```
        public static string decryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText)
    {
        string plaintext = null;

        //create an Rijndael object
        using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
        {
            //create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            //create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        //read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```

retrieving from resultset

```
                    using (Rijndael myRijndael = Rijndael.Create())
                {
                    temp5 = EncryptDecrypt.decryptStringFromBytes((byte[])reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Body")));
                }
```

Comment: You probably did not call FlushFinalBlock when encrypting or the padding does not match.

Comment: Show us the encryption and storing. You can't be sure that storing worked (why do you say so, btw?).

Comment: if i test the encryption with a string "i am testing".this value is stored in my table 221305b3a40332b912c1d356cdab4217

Comment: using (Rijndael myRijndael = Rijndael.Create())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", EncryptDecrypt.encryptStringToBytes(body));
                }

thats where its encrypting using the method encryptStringToBytes and parameter body which is a string

Comment: How did you verify that 221305b3a40332b912c1d356cdab4217 is correctly encrypted?

Comment: good point!!let me check

Comment: That's why posting complete code is usually a good idea :) Please post the code.

Comment: okay i updated the question to include the encryption method.how would i save the encryption to the db?using varbinary or blob?

Comment: You should close the `CryptoStream` before turning the `MemoryStream` into an array.

Comment: btw. Why are you using all those streams in the first place, instead of simply using `TransformFinalBlock`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not controlling key and IV in any way. This is kind of a problem... :) It results in your encryption being a random scrambling of the data because key and IV are randomly initialized by the framework.

Use the same key and IV for decryption as you are using them for encryption. Why do you think the database has to do with the problem? It hasn't and there is not evidence for that.